# How do I store additional Data in an authlogic session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I am using authlogic in my rails app.

my session controller looks like this

```
def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      ...
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Now, I want to store additional data in the session, e.g.

```
@user_session.new_projects_count = Projects.all_new_since(current_user.last_login_at).count
```

This doesn't work, any tips?

I also wanted to increment/decrement @user_session.new_projects_count in another controller

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend keeping authlogic as simple as possible (ie, don't add to it).

Once a user is logged in (after @user_session.save) you can then place any related information directly into session on your own.

If you want quick access to it, when you let up current_user you can always pull it at that time.

Comment: Have to agree, keep the user_session key to itself and store other things separate, create before_filters as necessary to pull back the data when needed.

Comment: okay, I just thought, there would be an elegant way with authlogic because you have all these models